# Equivalent of Java's Matcher.lookingAt() in Objective C

Tags: java, objective-c

I am porting a framework from Java to Objective C which heavily depends on regular expressions. Unfortunately the Java regular expressions API is a lot different from the Objective C API.

I am trying to use the **NSRegularExpression** class to evaluate the regular expressions. In Java this is completely different: you have to use the Pattern and Matcher classes.

There is something I can't figure out (among other things). What is the equivalent of Matcher.lookingAt() in Objective C? To put it in code. What would be the Objective C translation of the following code?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[aZ]");
boolean lookingAt = pattern.matcher("abc").lookingAt();
```

Thanks to anyone who knows! (btw the above example assigns true to the lookingAt boolean)

Comment: From the Java Docs that I read, lookingAt() does a prefix matching.  If that's what you want, then just use NSString's hasPrefix: method.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The "hasPrefix" method would have been fine if I wanted to just match the prefix of a string with another literal string. But at the spot I put "ObjC" in my question, I want it to work with a random regular expression as well. I don't think "hasPrefix" supports regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out! This is the NSRegularExpression equivalent of the Java code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[aZ]" options:0 error:&error];
if (error) {
    // Do something when an error occurs
}
NSString *candidate = @"abc";
BOOL lookingAt = [expression numberOfMatchesInString:candidate options:NSMatchingAnchored range:NSMakeRange(0, candidate.length)] > 0;
```

The emphasis here lies on the **NSMatchingAnchored** option when executing the expression! The docs say:

> **NSMatchingAnchored** Specifies that matches are limited to those at the
>   start of the search range. See
>   enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock: for a description
>   of the constant in context.

That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You may do something like

```
NSString *regex = @"ObjC";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@", regex]; 

if( [predicate evaluateWithObject:myString]) 
    NSLog(@"matches");
else
    NSLog(@"does not match");
```

take a look at [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795) guide for further options.

Comment: Thanks! But this is not exactly what I was looking for unfortunately. First of all your example is the equivalent of the Matcher.matches() method, not Matcher.lookingAt(). Second of all I really like to use NSRegularExpression since this is the preferred way of working with Regular Expressions in Objective C.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Instead of `SELF CONTAINS %@`, you may use `SELF BEGINSWITH %@`. As alternative, if you need to use `NSRegularExpression` you may consider using something like `– rangeOfFirstMatchInString:options:range:`, and check if the returned range starts from 0.

Comment: Actually, I don't think there's any "preferred way" of working with regular expressions in Objective-C.  Don't be fooled by the class name, both works, but I find NSPredicate to be easier to "read".  There are also more online resources to NSPredicate so I would just take a try at NSPredicate, and if that doesn't work, go back to NSRegularExpressions.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out using NSRegularExpressions! I will post the answer shortly.